# Getting error using gprof

Tags: gprof

I am trying to proile our software using gprof but when I execute the command

```
gprof <binary-name> gmon.out
```

I am getting the following error:

```
gprof: dimension unit changed between histogram records
gprof: from 'seconds'
gprof: to ''
```

I assume that my binary is generating gmon.out, therefore, compiler must have got the -pg switch during compilation.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try running gprof <binary-name> without mentioning the gmon.out as gprof reads the file from the current folder.

Answer (score 0):

The comment from AmeyaVS already alluded to the answer:

```
# compile and link with -pg
gcc -pg file.c -o file

# run program to generate the gmon.out file
./file

# run gprof on your executable with matching gmon.out
gprof file gmon.out
```

Answer (score -1):

Try not to run your application in daemon or parent-children mode.